# Tuleap - Increase Text Area characters

Tags: tuleap

I have installed Tuleap to my organizations, we have coded for email-parser options.
In that we have created a tracker with Title[String] and Description[Text Area] option.Can you suggest any options to increase the Text area characterization values.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the number of rows and columns you want to display in the field configuration (in Tracker administration > Manage field usage).

Comment: I have done that when a mail with 2 lakhs character hits the alm tool in the description option, mail content is displayed properly, when the artifact is assigned to the users, the user couldn't able to read that mail conversation , which is showing the source code of the mail content.